# The Laplace operator and exterior derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to solve an exercise involving the Laplacian but I'm unable to make any progress.

[image]

Here is what I have. In the following I am using the invariant formula for the exterior derivative.

a)

$$
d*df (X_0,X_1)
=d(-d(Jf)) (X_0,X_1)                                          \\
=-d(d(Jf))  (X_0,X_1)                                         \\
=- (d_{X_0} d Jf (X_1)- d_{X_1} d JF (X_0)- d Jf ([X_0,X_1])).  
$$

But now I do not see how the desired identity should follow from this.

b) Here, I have managed to show that exactness implies closedness. But I am struggling with the other direction. By assumption, we have $d \omega=0$ and

$$
0
=d \omega (X_0,X_1) 
=d_{X_1} \omega(X_0)-d_{X_0} (X_1)-\omega([X_0,X_1]) 
$$

which leads to

$$
\omega([X_0,X_1])=d_{X_1} \omega(X_0)-d_{X_0} (X_1)
$$

Now I have to find $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\omega=df$. Usually one would derive this fact from the Poincaré lemma. But in this case I think I have to choose a different way. But I do not see it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, (b) cannot be proved using (a). It's one particular case of Poincare lemma.

Comment: And your $Jf$ does not quite make sense.

Comment: I suppose you first write down first $df$, then $*df$, and then $d(*df)$.